# WITH clause within EA Sparx query

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to use WITH clauses within an EA Sparx query ?

I wrote this one :

```
with Activities as

    (
    select t_connector.start_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.* from t_object 
        join t_connector on t_connector.end_object_id=t_object.Object_id
        where t_object.Object_type= 'Activity'

    union

    select t_connector.end_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.*  from t_object  
        join t_connector on t_connector.start_object_id=t_object.Object_id
        where t_object.Object_type= 'Activity'

    )

select * from

    (
    select obj.object_id, count(other.object_id) as 'Activities' from
        t_object obj left join Activities as other on obj.Object_id=other.Object2_id

    group by obj.object_id
    ) as ac 

where object_id in (143306, 143321, 143226, 143326)
```

and it doesn't return any rows nor throw any errors, while the same query with the WITH-statement placed inline returns the expected results:

```
select * from
    (
    select obj.object_id, count(other.object_id) as 'Activities' from
        t_object obj left join 
            (
            select t_connector.start_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.* from t_object 
                join t_connector on t_connector.end_object_id=t_object.Object_id
                where t_object.Object_type= 'Activity'

            union

            select t_connector.end_object_id as Object2_id, t_object.*  from t_object  
                join t_connector on t_connector.start_object_id=t_object.Object_id
                where t_object.Object_type= 'Activity'

            )
        as other on obj.Object_id=other.Object2_id

    group by obj.object_id
    ) as ac 

where object_id in (143306, 143321, 143226, 143326)
```

I know that the SQL engine of EA is a bit tricky (e.g. the query cannot start by a comment).

Is there some tricks here to let WITH clauses working in EA ?

Answer (score 3):

EA does some basic checks on the queries. One of them is to check that the query starts with the keyword `select`.

**So, no there is no way to get EA to execute a search query starting with something else then `select`.**

In many circumstances however the `WITH` clause is used to perform recursive queries e.g. get all elements in a package and all it's subpackages.
For this specific case you can use the macro `#Branch#` which will be translated to a comma separated list of packageID's of the currently selected package and all of it's subpackages recursively.