# Add multiplicity as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiplicity

I use Sparx EA to build a relationship database (MS SQL Server).

The tool has a function to create charts.

I use the query:

```
SELECT system.Name AS Series, systemElement.Name AS GroupName
FROM t_object systemElement
INNER JOIN t_object system ON system.Object_ID = systemElement.ParentID
INNER JOIN t_object organization ON organization.ParentID = systemElement.Object_ID
INNER JOIN t_object post ON post.ParentID = organization.Object_ID AND post.Stereotype = 'ActualPost'

WHERE system.Name = 'Name of my main system object'
```

to get

[image]

which is great, just for the fact that the chart doesn't account for the multiplicity of the ActualPosts.

I can access the multiplicity with

```
SELECT system.Name AS Series, systemElement.Name AS GroupName, post.Name AS 'ActualPost', post.Multiplicity AS 'Multiplicity'
FROM t_object systemElement
INNER JOIN t_object system ON system.Object_ID = systemElement.ParentID
INNER JOIN t_object organization ON organization.ParentID = systemElement.Object_ID
INNER JOIN t_object post ON post.ParentID = organization.Object_ID AND post.Stereotype = 'ActualPost'

WHERE system.Name = 'Name of my main system object'
```

which results in a table like:

```
Series | GroupName | ActualPost | Multiplicity
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AA | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AB | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AC | 2
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer B | Post BA | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer B | Post BB | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer C | Post CA | 3
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer C | Post CB | 2
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer C | Post CC | 5
```

What I'm thinking is to add the multiplicity as rows, so turn a table like this:

```
Series | GroupName | ActualPost| Multiplicity
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AA | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AB | 1
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A | Post AC | 2
```

into

```
Series | GroupName
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A
Name of my main system element | OperationalPerformer A
```

Although I don't know how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Seems like Sparx EA has some limitations when it comes to SQL-queries...
The query HAS TO start with select, see [WITH clause within EA Sparx query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421769/with-clause-within-ea-sparx-query)

Is there a workaround for provided answers?

Comment: Do you want to repeat every row so many times as defined in Multiplicity column?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if the `Multiplicity <= 2047`

```
WITH myTable as (
    SELECT system.Name AS Series, systemElement.Name AS GroupName, post.Name AS 'ActualPost', post.Multiplicity AS 'Multiplicity'
    FROM t_object systemElement
    JOIN t_object system 
      ON system.Object_ID = systemElement.ParentID
    JOIN t_object organization 
      ON organization.ParentID = systemElement.Object_ID
    JOIN t_object post 
      ON post.ParentID = organization.Object_ID AND post.Stereotype = 'ActualPost'
    WHERE system.Name = 'Name of my main system object'
)
SELECT
    Series, GroupName
FROM
    myTable m
    JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v on m.Multiplicity > v.number
WHERE
    Type = 'P'
```

Modified `CTE` to `Derived Table` check this out

```
SELECT
    Series, GroupName
FROM (
    SELECT system.Name AS Series, systemElement.Name AS GroupName, post.Name AS 'ActualPost', post.Multiplicity AS 'Multiplicity'
    FROM t_object systemElement
    JOIN t_object system 
      ON system.Object_ID = systemElement.ParentID
    JOIN t_object organization 
      ON organization.ParentID = systemElement.Object_ID
    JOIN t_object post 
      ON post.ParentID = organization.Object_ID AND post.Stereotype = 'ActualPost'
    WHERE system.Name = 'Name of my main system object'
) DT
    JOIN MASTER.dbo.spt_values v on DT.Multiplicity > v.number
WHERE
    Type = 'P'
```

Comment: This will not work for Multiplicity > 2047

Comment: Thank you. Nothing returned.. Seemed strange. See my update in the question.

Comment: Yeah that's true, let me update the description

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT
        system.Name AS Series,
        systemElement.Name AS GroupName,
        post.Multiplicity AS 'Multiplicity',
        1 as Cnt
    FROM t_object systemElement
        INNER JOIN t_object system ON system.Object_ID = systemElement.ParentID
        INNER JOIN t_object organization ON organization.ParentID = systemElement.Object_ID
        INNER JOIN t_object post ON post.ParentID = organization.Object_ID AND post.Stereotype = 'ActualPost'
    WHERE system.Name = 'Name of my main system object'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Series,
        GroupName,
        Multiplicity,
        Cnt + 1 AS Cnt
    FROM T1
    WHERE Cnt < Multiplicity
)
SELECT
    Series,
    GroupName
FROM T1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- set recursion limit to undefined
```

Comment: Thank you. Nothing returned.. Seemed strange. See my update in the question.

Comment: Sql returns nothing when Multiplicity is null or < 1 or when original sql in your qeustion doesnt return data. Otherwise it works well

Comment: That might be, but apparently the tool I'm using has some limitations, as I wrote in the updated question. So in the tool, this dows nothing.